# "Top" style not calculating correctly from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Okay, starting over as I'm new at all of this and, as Sebastian points out, the problem is likely elsewhere.

This is a combination lock which was created by Derek Hill. I've reformatted it by cutting its size in half. In doing so, the size of the dial after spinning doesn't work out right -- when you spin the numbers, you can see that the height of the numbers begins dropping and is no longer vertically centered. It creeps down by about 0.5px each time.

I first notice the problem at the variable "temporTopEarlier". I cannot understand why the "top" for the dial is 0.5px more than it should be (-157 instead of -157.5). I think this is causing my problems. I expected a truncation of decimals, but I don't see where that would happen.

I'm new at this, so apologies for the many poor elements to the code, format, and question. Thanks!

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <style>
    #lock-plate{
        padding: 15px 0;
        border: 0.5px solid #cfd3d6;
        background: #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        width: 243px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 0%,#949ba0 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 0%,#949ba0 100%);
        border-radius: 2px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        position: absolute;
        top: 6%;
        left: 43%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    #lock-wrapper{
        width: 220px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 4px;
        border-radius: 3.5px;
        height: 60px;
        border: .5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c4c4c4 0%,#676767 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c4c4c4 0%,#676767 100%);
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .lock-dial{
        height: 60px;
        width: 34px;
        margin-left: 5.5px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c9093 0%,#b6babd 9%,#ccd2d6 18%,#ffffff 55%,#ccd2d6 82%,#b6babd 91%,#8c9093 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8c9093 0%,#b6babd 9%,#ccd2d6 18%,#ffffff 55%,#ccd2d6 82%,#b6babd 91%,#8c9093 100%);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        cursor: move;
    }

    #lock-wrapper .lock-dial ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 26.5px;
        line-height: 35px;
        color: #414f6b;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #212c42;
        transition: box-shadow .45s linear, color .25s linear;
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .45s linear, color .25s linear;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: #012443">
        <div id="lock-plate">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
            <div id="lock-wrapper">
                <!-- <div class="welcome-message">WELCOME!</div> -->
                <div class="lock-dial" id="dial-one"><ul data-combo-num="0"><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>0</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>




    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-hlKLmzaRlE8SCJC1Kw8zoUbU8BxA+8kR3gseuKfMjxA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
    $(function(){

    var comboArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var combination = [4, 3, 9, 2, 0];

    var gridIncrement = $( ".lock-dial ul" ).css('line-height').replace('px', '')/2; // this is correct, 17.5
    var numNums = $( ".lock-dial:eq(0) ul li" ).length; // 10 numbers
    var halfHeight = gridIncrement*numNums; // this is correct, 175
    var initTop = -(halfHeight-gridIncrement); //this is correct, -157.5

    $( ".lock-dial ul" ).css('top', initTop); // this is correct -157.5

    $( ".lock-dial ul" ).draggable({
        grid: [ 0, gridIncrement ],
        axis: 'y',
        drag: function(){
            var dragDir = $(this).css('top').replace('px', '') < initTop ? "up" : "down";
            
            if(dragDir == "up"){
                var curNum = parseFloat($(this).find('li:last-child').text()) + 1;
                if(curNum < 10){
                    $(this).append('<li>'+curNum+'</li>');
                }else{
                    $(this).append('<li>0</li>');
                };
            }else{
                var curNum = parseFloat($(this).find('li:first-child').text()) - 1;
                var thisTop = parseFloat($(this).css('margin-top')); //seems right, starts at 0 and goes down by 35s
                
                $(this).css({
                    marginTop: thisTop-(gridIncrement*2)
                });
                                    
                if(curNum > -1){
                    $(this).prepend('<li>'+curNum+'</li>');
                }else{
                    $(this).prepend('<li>9</li>');
                };
            };
            
            var temporTopEarlier = parseFloat($(this).css('top')); // this is wrong -157, should be -157.5
            console.log("tempor top earlier " + temporTopEarlier);
        },
        
        stop: function(){
        
            //MATHS     
            var halfHeight = 175;
            var initTop = -157.5;
            var negOrPos = $(this).css('margin-top').replace('px', '') > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            var tempor_top = parseFloat($(this).css('top')); // this is wrong -174.5, should be -175
            console.log("tempor_top " + tempor_top);
            console.log(this);

            var thisTopTotal = parseFloat($(this).css('top')) + Math.abs(initTop); // this first part is wrong, -17 instead of -17.5
            var marginMinified = parseFloat(Math.abs($(this).css('margin-top').replace('px', ''))) - thisTopTotal;
            var numIncs = Math.floor(marginMinified/(halfHeight*2));
            var totalDif = numIncs*(halfHeight*2);
            var topTen = (marginMinified - totalDif)*negOrPos;
            var activeIndex = Math.abs(topTen/(gridIncrement*2)) + (halfHeight/(gridIncrement*2));
            console.log("halfHeight " + halfHeight);
            console.log("initTop " + initTop);
            console.log("thisTopTotal " + thisTopTotal);
            console.log("marginMinified " + marginMinified);
            console.log("numIncs " + numIncs);
            console.log("topTen " + topTen);
            console.log("totalDif " + totalDif);
            console.log("activeIndex " + activeIndex); // this should be a number in 0.5 increments and it's not
                            
            $(this).attr("data-combo-num", $(this).find('li').eq(activeIndex).text()).css({
                top: -157.5,
                marginTop: topTen
            }).find('li').slice(20).remove();
            
            for(var i=0; i<$( ".lock-dial ul" ).length; i++){
                comboArray[i] = $( ".lock-dial ul:eq("+i+")" ).attr("data-combo-num");
            }
        }
    });
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: The `.replace('px', '')` is superfluous since you’re already using `parseFloat`. Other than that, please [edit] your post and include a [mre]. I can’t reproduce this issue. This does not appear to be about `this` at all.

Comment: There could be a style inherited from CSS with the `!important` flag, so it's overriding the `style` attribute. The `.css()` method returns the computed style.